# Local variable 'newfile' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

'''Want to rename a file removing all the bad chars that are in the array "bad_pattern".
I started by reading all the chars from the bad pattern and then comparing to the chars that are in the file name.
If it find any then is replaced by a "_" and when the loop ends file with no strange chars is returned to be used later.

Then in the method `moveFiles()` I should get the output of the previews method and save it in the variable `newfile`.
Finally I want to rename the file.

I am getting the error:

```
local variable 'newfile' referenced before assignment
```

Here is my code:

```
file = t#est.txt
bad_pattern= ["ã", "â", "é", "è", ", "ò", "ù", "û", "~", "^", "#"","\s"]

def filename_replacer(file):

    for char in bad_pattern:
        for char_good in file:
            if char_good == char:
                newfile = file.replace(char_good, "_")
    return newfile


def moveFiles():
    files = os.listdir(startDir+"/"+app)
    for file in files:
        newfile = filename_replacer(file)
        try:
            os.rename(file,newfile)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

Comment: This is not your actual code. `file = t#est.txt` would throw an error long before the error you are seeing, then `bad_pattern`. Please make sure your code is an accurate representation of what you're looking at. You also don't show the functions being called.

Comment: Your are correct just forced that string to illustrate my point :)
But the solution was already found by Mark Tolonen

Answer (score 2):

A traceback is helpful, but it looks like the problem is here:

```
def filename_replacer(file):
    for char in bad_pattern:
        for char_good in file:
            if char_good == char:
                # If next line never executes, newfile is undefined for return
                newfile = file.replace(char_good, "_")
    return newfile
```

Change `newfile` to `file` and it should fix the problem.  `file` will be unchanged if no bad patterns are found.

Comment: Niiiice!! solved
My project is finally finished!!
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving you `newfile` variable inside the try/except statement. I don't fully understand, but `try` statements happen in a different scope that your main function, so defining `newfile` outside the try statement will not define it inside it.
**try this**

```
def moveFiles():
    files = os.listdir(startDir+"/"+app)
    for file in files:
        try:
            newfile = filename_replacer(file)
            os.rename(file,newfile)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```